# What is the use of a bitwise and, (&1), in javascript?

Tags: javascript

From the [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Simple_synth) here,

```js
function notePressed(event) {
  if (event.buttons & 1) {
    let dataset = event.target.dataset;

    if (!dataset["pressed"]) {
      let octave = +dataset["octave"];
      oscList[octave][dataset["note"]] = playTone(dataset["frequency"]);
      dataset["pressed"] = "yes";
    }
  }
}
```

What is the use of `event.buttons & 1`? Why is a bitwise AND being used?

Comment: "Why is a bitwise AND being used?" - because `event.buttons` is an integer value. It's a syntactically succinct way to check if `events.buttons` *contains* the bit `1` - as it's a flags (bitfield) integer which could also be `3` (buttons 1 and 2), 2 (just button 2), etc.

Comment: @dai maybe that should be an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `event.buttons` returns an integer value, which represents that which mouse button is pressed. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/buttons#Return_value) it returns -

- `0` : No button or un-initialized
- `1` : Primary button (usually the left button)
- `2` : Secondary button (usually the right button)
- `4` : Auxiliary button (usually the mouse wheel button or middle button)
- `8` : 4th button (typically the "Browser Back" button)
- `16` : 5th button (typically the "Browser Forward" button)

So, ultimately what do we get from this `event.buttons`? An integer value.

Now come to your shared code snippet. What does the line `if (event.buttons & 1)` mean? Let's check some example of, what does the `& 1` do with 32 bits integer.

```js
0 & 1 => 0
1 & 1 => 1
2 & 1 => 0
3 & 1 => 1
23 & 1 => 1
46 & 1 => 0
```

So, if we perform `& 1` with any 32 bits integer number then for **Even** numbers it returns `0` and for **Odd** numbers it returns `1`. We can easily detect any odd/even numbers by using ***bitwise AND 1*** operation.

Now you know `0` is a falsy value so the `if` condition never passes if we get `0` from the statement. So, `if (event.buttons & 1)` checks if the `event.buttons` gives an **Odd** number then execute the `if` block, otherwise not.

I hope I can clear it.